# For UIScrollview, how can I use my own panGestureRecognizer but allow the scrollView to use its recognizers for bounces?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to implement my own pan-scrolling within the contentSize but allow the scrollView to handle bounces outside the contentSize. I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried requiresGestureRecognizerToFail:, setting it between all of the scrollView's recognizers and my pan one.

I also tried implementing the three delegate methods on my pan recognizer, returning YES when the contentOffset is outside of the contentSize.

Any tips or suggestions are welcome! Even if you don't know the solution, but have an idea that COULD work, please post! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate)

With this method:

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch`

And make your conditional check inside, disable your scroll view, and let the gesture take control...something like (completely making up numbers):

```
if (self.scrollView.contentSize > 100) {
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(reenableScrollView) afterDelay:0.3f];
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
```

Then re-enable the scroll view

```
- (void)reenableScrollView {
    self.scrollView.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Just by itself? The scroll views recognizers seem to be overriding mine when I do this, even when I return no

Comment: Are you sure the method is getting called? ..You've put a breakpoint, or an NSLog in there, and it gets hit?

Comment: Could it be the scroll views recognizers have priority?

Comment: My pan recognizer isn't being called now. I can make a mini project later to show what I am doing. It seems the gesture recognizer in should receive touch is my own... I'm blocking my own recognizer! The delegate is set on my pan recognizer, scroll view ones can't be changed